# Is it possible to calculate falling speed of iPhone?

Tags: ios, accelerometer

My app will have one `UILabel` that displays the current speed of the iPhone. And of course if iPhone is falling down, the falling speed will update to that label aslo. For short distances, I believe GPS cannot do this, and the accelerometer is also not suitable. 
Is this task possible? If so, how to implement it?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Accurately? No.

Answer (score 0):

No, GPS can not do this. (not one in  the IPhone). But it is possible with accelerometer ( but do not await high precision )